# Error on package-list-packages

Tags: package-repositories

I've started to get the following errors when running package-list-packages. Searching online hasn't come up with anything. If anyone can suggest a cause and/or a solution I'd be very grateful.

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done

error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 113

" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80)

error in process sentinel: Error retrieving: http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 113

" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 80)

Package refresh done
```

Comment: elpa isn't always available. I am not sure that should affect `package-list-packages` as this command should read from your local list.

Comment: Thank you.  It's just that I've never had this error before and it been going on for almost a week.  I'm surprised it hasn't been more widely reported.

Comment: Works for me, but there have been some other reports: https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/arnbhb/cant_reach_elpa_for_the_last_couple_of_days/